# Spring Integration- FTP should synchronize with local folder

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have ftp location files and have local folder, on first time the files are copied to local and on restarting the server(Currently it is copying already copied files to the local folder) it should not look for the files which are  already exist in the local and it should lookup for new files only. Please let me know is it possible to achieve it using Spring-Integration ftp?
I have added Filter also but still it is not working, please let me know where I am going wrong,

```java
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "inputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
public MessageSource<?> receive() {
    FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource messageSource = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(synchronizer());
    PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore metadataStore = new PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore();
    FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter acceptOnceFilter = new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore,"*.xml");

    File Temp = new File(TEMP_FOLDER);

    metadataStore.setBaseDirectory(TEMP_FOLDER);
    messageSource.setLocalDirectory(Temp);
    messageSource.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(false);

    messageSource.setLocalFilter(acceptOnceFilter);

    return messageSource;
}

private AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer<FTPFile> synchronizer() {
    folderCleanUp();
    AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer<FTPFile> fileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(sessionFactory());
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(ftpFileLocation);
    fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\.xml$");
    FtpRegexPatternFileListFilter ftpRegexPatternFileListFilter = new FtpRegexPatternFileListFilter(pattern);
    fileSynchronizer.setFilter(ftpRegexPatternFileListFilter);
    return fileSynchronizer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify [Artem's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790343/spring-integration-ftp-should-synchronize-with-local-folder#comment63142288_37794563) about implementing your custom `FileListFilter`, here is an example of such filter (aimed to filter out files older than given moment):

```java
@Component
public class OldFilesFilter extends AbstractFileListFilter<FTPFile> {
  // (oldFilesTimestamp field declaration and its source)

  @Override
  protected boolean accept(FTPFile file) {
    String fileName = file.getName();
    long fileTimestamp = file.getTimestamp().getTimeInMillis();
    ZonedDateTime fileModTimestamp = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(fileTimestamp), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    boolean isFileAcceptable = fileModTimestamp.isAfter(oldFilesTimestamp);
    if (log.isTraceEnabled()) {
      log.trace("File {}:\n" +
          "file timestamp : {};\n" +
          "given timestamp: {};\n" +
          "file is new    : {}",
          fileName, fileModTimestamp, oldFilesTimestamp, isFileAcceptable);
    }
    return isFileAcceptable;
  }
}
```

Also note that Spring Integration allows multiple filters to be applied to single file source at the same time. This can be achieved with `CompositeFileListFilter`:

```java
  private CompositeFileListFilter<FTPFile> remoteFileFilter() {
    FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter persistentFilter =
                            new FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore, "remoteProcessedFiles.");
    return new CompositeFileListFilter<>(Arrays.asList(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.zip"),
                                                       persistentFilter,
                                                       oldFilesFilter /*known from previous example*/));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Take a look to the `local-filter` property and `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` is for you to track local files via external `MetadataStore`, e.g. Redis, MongoDb or any other which keeps the data over system restarts.

Comment: Regardless of the filters, files that are already in the local directory are not copied again; see [the synchronized code here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/remote/synchronizer/AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java#L293). The local filter needs to be persistent to prevent messages being emitted for already processed files after a restart.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I have added the above Filter code,
but still it is not working any thing else needs to be done

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell, I need to copy the same file(already copied to local file) if there is data modified and replaced from ftp and if I try to restart the server the everything is copied to local. Instead of I need to copy only the change file and replace the local even without restarting the server also. Please let me know what I should do.

Comment: In that case you have to remove the local file after processing. It won't be resynched otherwise. Good idea anyway to conserve disk. But using a persistent filter is critical

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell,    I was using FileUtils.forceDelete(new File("temp")); to delete the folder and if i copied and processed if it got deleted it will pull the same file again and it will be a chain process .Once the system restarted it is deleted. I need even if the system is running it should identify the files which got modified with the same name and it should pick for process.Please let me know is it possible using spring-ftp integration

Comment: That looks like a bit different question, anyway take a look into `FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`, which really counts the `file.getTimestamp()` to compare files in the store with those in the remote dir. The same `local-filter` is still should be there.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell & Artem, I have tried the above mentioned code as mentioned with FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter but the file if I delete in ftp remains in local. Is there any other sync is required for AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer. if I tried using synchronizeToLocalDirectory the application is not working. Please let me know what I need to modify.

Comment: ??? `if I delete in ftp remains in local`. There is really no such an event to listen for. Remote FTP and local dir are fully separate resources and don't know about each other anything. The `synchronizeToLocalDirectory` is just only for coping **existing** remote files to local dir if it is accepted by `filter`. You may try to implement your custom `FileListFilter` with a logic to clean files in `MetadataStore`, which don't appear with the next `synchronizeToLocalDirectory` though. But there is no such an out-of-the-box functionality.